# Erro em tempo de execução '424' ao executar SQL

Tags: sql, microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, microsoft-access

Estou tentando mandar dados do excel para o access através de uma macro. Editei em cima de uma pronta e me parecia que estava fazendo a mesma coisa, mas dá "Erro em tempo de execução 424 - o objeto é obrigatório" quando chega na parte do "Execute SQL". Não consigo achar meu erro.

```
Sub Insere()
Dim gConexao As ADODB.Connection
a2019 = Cells(2, 2).Value
a2020 = Cells(2, 3).Value
a2021 = Cells(2, 4).Value
a2022 = Cells(2, 5).Value
a2023 = Cells(2, 6).Value
a2024 = Cells(2, 7).Value
lsInserir a2019, a2020, a2021, a2022, a2023, a2024
End Sub


Sub lsInserir(a2019, a2020, a2021, _
                      a2022, a2023, a2024)
    Dim lSQL As String

    lsConectar
 lSQL = "INSERT INTO Tabela1 &(a2019, a2020, a2021, a2022, a2023, a2024)" & _
    "VALUES (" & a2019 & "," & a2020 & "," & a2021 & "," & a2022 & "," & a2023 & "," & a2024 & ")"

    gConexao.Execute lSQL
    lsDesconectar
End Sub

Sub lsConectar()
    Dim strConexao As String
    Set gConexao = New ADODB.Connection

    strConexao = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\2005866\Documents\testeleituradados.accdb;Persist Security Info=False"

    gConexao.Open strConexao
End Sub

Sub lsDesconectar()
    If Not gConexao Is Nothing Then
        gConexao.Close
        Set gConexao = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Tem certeza de que as aspas da string lSQL estão corretas? Se estiverem então existe pelo menos um & errado. De qualque forma me parece estranho que uma mesma célula contenha tanto o nome do campo na base de dados quanto seu valor.

Comment: é que o nome do campo lá no access chama "a2019","a2020", etc e dei o mesmo nome pra variavel que pega o valor na célula... não é a mesma coisa.

Comment: Então creio que tem um & sobrando antes da lista de nomes dos campos.

Comment: Sobre as aspas... já tentei sem aspas, com " ' ' ", com só simples... tudo. Dá o mesmo erro. Sobre o &...qual está errado?

Comment: tirei esse & antes (que nem tinha visto ele aí, mas relamente não parece certo) e ainda dá o mesmo erro...

Comment: por algum motivo eu tirei as funções que tavam uma chamando a outra e coloquei tudo juntinho na sequência e funcionou...vai entender. Obrigada :)

Comment: No início do seu código, mude para: 
Dim gConexao As New ADODB.Connection e teste. Se não der certo, coloque um break point na linha do .Execute SQL para ver se a instrução está sendo montada corretamente (use o debug.print lSQL).